# Responsive website blanking at small resolutions on mobiles

Tags: css, jsp, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, media-queries

I am involved in developing a responsive website, and am using the Twitter Bootstrap (2.3.2) framework as a base. I made the site in HTML, on a staging site setup, and it worked great at all resolutions on all devices.

On the live site, all resolutions work great on a computer (ie. changing the browser window size), right down to 320px. It works great on tablets, and on larger smartphones, including landscape orientation on an iPhone 5. In portrait orientation on iPhone 5, both orientations on iPhone 4, and on an Android with smaller resolutions, the page blanks - ie. shows white.

The only thing I can think of that's significantly different between staging and live, is that it's now in a Java environment - could that be interacting in a weird way with the responsive stuff?? I'm totally stumped here, I don't even know what to Google for... has anyone ever experienced anything like this??

Comment: I'd start by doing a diff on the HTML source, JS and CSS files between your staging and live sites. Are you using JAWR on the Java webapp? There are known issues with its CSS processing of Bootstrap CSS files that could be causing this.

Comment: The problem with that is that they're quite different - one was done with very little content or placeholder content, and in HTML, and one was done in a full live-client-data Java environment. There are all sorts of things that are different :/ I realise that may be part of the problem, but I was hoping someone might be able to give me something to go by. Otherwise I will have to spend a few days with the Java developers stripping everything out until it works, which is time consuming in a project that's already running overtime :/

Comment: I just asked - we don't use JAWR.